# Wrong method invoked when using method reference to implement functional interface

Tags: java, functional-interface

```java
@FunctionalInterface
interface MyIF {

    void init();
    default void myTest() {
        System.out.println("myTest interface Method");
    }
}

class A implements MyIF {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        myTest();
    }

    @Override
    public void myTest() {
        System.out.println("myTest class Method");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        MyIF my = a::myTest;
        my.myTest(); 
  }
}
```

**Output**

> myTest interface Method

**Expected**

> myTest class Method

I tried this code and expected the same result:

```java
A a = new A();
MyIF my = new A();
my.myTest();
```

**Output**

> myTest class Method

Why are the results different?

Answer (score 3):

`a::myTest` means use `myTest()` as the required function in an implementation of the functional interface `MyIF`. The function it must take the place of is the `init()` method, **not** the `myTest` method. Functional interfaces have one missing implementation, and in this case, it is the `init()` method. So this new implementation of `MyIF` has the the `init` as specified by `a::myTest`, and the `myTest` as specified by `default void myTest()` in `MyIF`. It is not an instance of `A`: it is like having:

```
A a = new A();
MyIF my = new MyIF() {
    public void init() {
        a.myTest();
    }
};
```

---

In the second case, your `my` *is* actually an instance of `A`, and method implementations in a class overrule default implementations in an interface, so you get the `myTest` method from `A`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question :).

As @khelwood has pointed out, this line:

```
MyIF my = a::myTest;
```

creates a lambda binding to the `init()` method of the MyIF interface.

When the compiler encounters this, it creates a new MyIF reference that is only linked to the instance of A for its implementation of `init()`. Since the compiler can only choose a single method to provide the `@FunctionalInterface` behavior, it has to choose the non-default method. Otherwise the compiler can't know which method the interface is defining as its functional/lambda signature. If you tried to have 2 standard interface methods with no default implementations, you'd get a compiler error for this reason (even if the signatures were different).

It might be clearer if you add a line to your code:

```
        A a = new A();
        MyIF my = a::myTest;
        my.init();
        my.myTest();
```

Now you can see in the output that the `init()` method called by the lambda still calls the `myTest()` implementation in A.

In general it's probably wise to try to avoid default implementations in functional interfaces to make this less confusing :).

Effective Java (3rd Edition) items 21 and 43 are relevant here.